# Distribution of all point to point distances on a square $L \times L$ lattice?

Tags: combinatorics, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Is it possible to derive a probability density function $P(d,L)$ which gives probability of having a point to point distance $d$ on a $2D$ square lattice of size $L$ or at least it's asymptotic behavior ?

Comment: It makes more sense to ask how many distinct distances exist between points of the lattice.  A simple upper bound is $\frac 12(L+2)(L+1)$ which is the number of pairs $(a,b)$ with $0 \le a,b \le L, a\le b$.  From that we would have to subtract the number of distances that are represented twice, as $5$ can come from $(0,5)$ and $(3,4)$ and $\sqrt {65}$ can come from $(1,8)$ and $(6,7)$.  I don't have a good way of estimating the last part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isn't total number of distinct distances simply $\binom{L^2}{2} = \frac{(L^2)(L^2-1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: No because many of them are the same.  Any pair of neighboring points gives a distance of $1$, for example.  I am choosing the offsets horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Caloculations show a very spiky probability distribution for all $L \lt 7$. I doubt any nice distribution will emerge for larger $L$. Have you attempted any simulations?

Comment: This question related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732511/what-is-the-distribution-of-distances-between-two-random-points-in-a-cubic-latti). When I looked at Mathai's [paper](http://www.math.utep.edu/faculty/moschopoulos/Publications/1999-Distance_Between_Random_Points_in_a_Cube.pdf), he generalized results from the squares over reals from Ghosh. If an exact distribution was found, I wonder if the 3D version could be solved in a similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

Two lattice points which have a horizontal (or vertical) distance of $a$ and a vertical (or horizontal) distance of $b$, will have a point to point distance of $$d(a,b) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

In an grid of $L \times L$ points, where $ a \lt L$ and $b \lt L$, there is a nice formula for the number of instances of the distance $d(a,b)$. For a given $a$ and $b$, where $a \ge b$, the number of instances of the distance $d(a,b)$, is 
$$
  n =
\begin{cases}
2(L-a)(L-b),  & \text{if $b=0$ or $b=a$} \\
4(L-a)(L-b), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
Since we know the total number of instances of all possible distances is $\binom {L^2}{2}$, it seems we can directly compute the probability of a given distance for a given lattice size.

However, as Ross Millikan pointed out, some distances can be generated in more than one way, i.e. for some distances $d(a,b) = d(e,f)$ where $(a,b) \ne (e,f)$. The distances where this occurs (or rather the square of those distances) can be seen [here](https://oeis.org/A118882).

No formula for these distances appears available. Using the formula above, it is however fairly easy to make an algorithm which computes the probabilities. I did it by running through all possible values of $a$ and $b$ for a given grid size $L$, finding the distances which could be arrived at for different $a$ and $b$ and adding the instances for these together.

Below is a graph showing the probability distribution for $L=10$

[image]

And here is the distribution for $L=40$

[image]

There seems to be an asymptotic nature to this.

[image]

The above is for $L=70$. The extra large spikes occur where a distance can be generated in more than one way.